# Apache Virtual Host error

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Before I begin to explain my issue, it's worth noting that my DNS records are setup correctly.

This is a weird error, I have a server with the ip: `82.4.165.27` hosting several virtual directories. I'm using Apache2.

My `http://test.fakepath/` url is *usually* setup to forward to `https://test.fakepath`. That works. At the moment it simply loads the expected webpage.

So the `http://test.fakepath/` url works as expected, however the `https://test.fakepath/` does not. It incorrectly loads `https://home.fakepath/`.

For some reason, the apache server doesn't recognise the `*:443` version of the `https://test.fakepath/` site.

`apache2ctl -S` Output:

```
[Sat Apr 11 03:31:29.843972 2015] [core:error] [pid 11925] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name *443 -- ignoring!
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server home.fakepath (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:6)
         port 443 namevhost home.fakepath (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:6)
         port 443 namevhost cloud.fakepath (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:20)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server home.fakepath (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost home.fakepath (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost cloud.fakepath (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:15)
         port 80 namevhost test.fakepath (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:29)
         port 80 namevhost vb.fakepath (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:44)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="steven" id=1000 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

My file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName home.fakepath
        ServerAdmin admin@fakepath
        Redirect permanent / https://home.fakepath/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName home.fakepath
        ServerAdmin admin@fakepath
        DocumentRoot /var/www/home.fakepath
        SSLCertificateFile /home/steven/.ssl/home.fakepath.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/steven/.ssl/home.fakepath.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/steven/.ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.fakepath
        ServerAdmin admin@fakepath
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test.fakepath
        #Redirect permanent / https://test.fakepath/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *443>
        ServerName test.fakepath
        ServerAdmin admin@fakepath
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test.fakepath
        SSLCertificateFile /home/steven/.ssl/test.fakepath.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/steven/.ssl/test.fakepath.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/steven/.ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason, the apache server doesn't recognise the *:443 version of the https://test.fakapath/ site.

You need to change

```
 <VirtualHost *443>
```

to:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
```

in the vhost for test.fakapath

(notice the missing colon in your config)